# How to get my overloaded << operator to print out my function?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I am having trouble with an overloaded operator for my Cinema class, which is supposed to print out the list of all movies, the list of times associated with it, and then the release date. I think I have the printAll() function to work fine, but I seem to be having troubles with getting it to print out in the right way in the overloaded function.

This is the date class

```
class Date 
{
    public: 
        Date(int = 0, int = 0, int = 0);
        //…. 
        // other as appropriate 
        bool operator < (Date&);
        bool operator == (Date &); 
        friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &, const Date &); 

    private:
        int day, month, year;
};
```

The movie class where date is housed

```
class Movie 
{
    public:
        Movie(string& name, int yyyy, int mm, int dd) : name(name), releaseDate(Date(yyyy, mm, dd)) {};
        const Date & getReleaseDate(); 
        // other? 
        bool operator < (Movie& r);
        bool operator == (Movie &); 
        Movie & operator ++ (); 
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, Movie &); 
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const Movie &); 

    private: 
        Movie() = default; 
        const Date releaseDate; 
        string name; 
        int rating;
};
```

The Cinema class which call the function printAll(), through and overloaded << operator as well, and print out all the movies, their times and their release dates

```
class Cinema
{
    public: 
        Cinema() = default; 
        Cinema(Cinema &); 
        void addMovie(Movie *, list<int> & );
        friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, Cinema &); 
        //Movie * operator[](int); 
        void movieRunningAt(Movie &, list<int> & ); 
        void printShowTimes(const Movie *);
        void printAll();

    private:
        std::list<Movie *> movies;
        map<const Movie*, list<int>> movie_times;
};
```

The overloaded Date operator

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const Date & dt)
{
    os << dt.month << "/" << dt.day << "/" << dt.year << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

And this is the printAll() function.

```
void Cinema::printAll() 
{
    cout << "All movies and times for Cimea\n";
    for (auto & mov : movie_times)
    {
        cout << mov.first << ": ";
        for (auto & tim : mov.second)
        {
            cout << tim << " ";
        }
        for (auto & li : movies)
        {
            if (li == mov.first)
            {
                cout << li->getReleaseDate << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The overloaded << operator for Cinema

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const Cinema & ci)
{
    os << ci.printAll() << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

The error it is giving me is

```
"void Cinema::printAll(void): cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Cimea' to 'Cimea &'"
```

and also

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3867   'Movie::getReleaseDate': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Comment: Declare your `printAll` function `const`: `void printAll() const;`.  For the second error, you need `cout << li->getReleaseDate () << "\n";` (note the brackets).

Comment: Why does `Movie` have a version of `operator<<` that is overloaded for non-const references?

Comment: And _call_ `getReleaseDate`: `cout << li->getReleaseDate() << "\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the compiler know that `printAll` isn't going to make changes to the object (that is, that it's good to be called by const objects). So make the header:

```
void printAll() const;
```

and

```
void Cinema::printAll() const {
```

The second error is because you've forgotten parenthesis on your function call. Change

```
cout << li->getReleaseDate << "\n";
```

to

```
cout << li->getReleaseDate() << "\n";
```

Comment: That helped a lot, but now it is telling me a new error, ```binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)``` So, why does it say that the right hand operand is void?

Comment: @aaronscott You're doing `os << ci.printAll() << "\n";` when it should just be `ci.printAll()`